# CMake SublimeText file_regex issues

Tags: regex, cmake, sublimetext3

I've started using cmake 3.7.0-rc1 few hours ago and I'm wondering what's wrong with the build systems generated for SublimeText, here's an example of one of the provided build systems:

```
{
    "name": "Project - all",
    "cmd": ["nmake", "/NOLOGO", "/f", "Makefile", "VERBOSE=1", "all"],
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$"
}
```

But using that file_regex is not working at all with my error lines, instead I need to use something similar to this:

```
{
    "name": "Project - all",
    "cmd": ["nmake", "/NOLOGO", "/f", "Makefile", "VERBOSE=1", "all"],
    "working_dir": "${file_path}",
    "file_regex": "^([^(]+)\\((\\d+)\\):\\s*()(.*)$"
}
```

My error lines look like this:

```
D:\sources\personal\python\console\swig_tests\tutorial1\tutorial.cxx(11): error C2065: 'output_value': undeclared identifier
D:\sources\personal\python\console\swig_tests\tutorial1\tutorial.cxx(13): error C2065: 'output_value': undeclared identifier
D:\sources\personal\python\console\swig_tests\tutorial1\tutorial.cxx(15): error C2065: 'ret': undeclared identifier
```

So, is this a well-known issue/bug with CMake or I'm missing something?

Comment: Those look like make errors, nothing to do with ST. Try running make with the same arguments from the command line. I expect you'll get the same errors.

Comment: @GerardRoche I guess you didn't understand the question at all, please read again. Or maybe my English is kind of confusing, what I meant is the file_regex provided by CMake won't highlight/goto error lines properly on SublimeText

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @arrowd I'm using `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23918 for x64`

Comment: Ah, yes, you want Sublime Text to capture the errors so that you can F4 to goto the file and line of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **result_file_regex**
>       A Perl-style regular expression to capture up to four fields of error information from a results view, namely: filename, line number, column number and error message. Use groups in the pattern to capture this information. The filename field and the line number field are required.
>
> — http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html?highlight=result_file_regex

*It says "result_file_regex" in the docs, but that's wrong, the key for builds "file_regex".*

The following should match the filename and line number:

```
"file_regex": "^([^\(]+)\(([0-9]+)\):.*$"
```

The errors don't show a column number. Make the column number optional:

```
"file_regex": "^([^\(]+)\(([0-9]+)\):([0-9]+)?.*$"
```

Add the error message capture group:

```
"file_regex": "^([^\(]+)\(([0-9]+)\):([0-9]+)? error (.*)$"
```

So the following:

```
D:\sources\personal\python\console\swig_tests\tutorial1\tutorial.cxx(15): error C2065: 'ret': undeclared identifier
```

Will match:

- Filename: `D:\sources\personal\python\console\swig_tests\tutorial1\tutorial.cxx`
- Line: `15`
- Column: `None`
- Error: `C2065: 'ret': undeclared identifier`

The regex could be better, but that will work for all similar error messages like you've shown. I hope I've show enough to adapt it for additional errors formats or to make it a more general use regex.

Comment: Isn't this a bug in CMake? Should this be added to their bug tracker?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, also... what @usr1234567 asked

Comment: The cmake errors are not cmake bugs. There are undeclared identifiers on lines 11, 13, and 15 of the file `D:\sources\personal\python\console\swig_tests\tutorial1\tutorial.cxx`. Read up on cmake undeclared identifiers.